# How to pipe output and log files to S3 using FFMPEG

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I'm saving my FFMPEG output directly from my EC2 to S3 using:

```
ffmpeg -i ${input} -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+faststart -hide_banner -y pipe:1 | aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/video/output.mp4
-
```

which works perfectly, but I would like to add my `ffmpeg.log` and `progress.log` like this:

```
ffmpeg -i ${input} -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+faststart -hide_banner -y -progress progress.log pipe:1 | aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/video/output.mp4 &> ffmpeg.log
-
```

but adding the logs throws errors and saves the logs on my EC2. I'm sure it's not even close to what I need. I tried adding multiple pipes as well, but no joy.

How can I add save my log files to S3 with my output files using ffmpeg?

Comment: Maybe try `2> ffmpeg.log`. Try the same thing on ffmpeg like `ffmpeg -i ${input} -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+faststart -hide_banner -y pipe:1 2> progress.log`.  Either way, the logs should appear in your current working directory unless you provide a different path.

Comment: You could probably do this with a named pipe or maybe a subshell that only redirects StdOut, but why? The main reason to send the primary output directly to S3 is to avoid buffering a potentially large file locally. The logfiles shouldn't be that large.

Comment: @Jason I tried your suggestion, but it saved it on the EC2 instance instead of S3.

Answer (score 0):

Your logs are going to go to the current working directory.  You will need to upload these separately. Since we are interested in logs, I thought you might want to do some error checking as well.  If not, just remove the stuff between the `if [...]` and `fi`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This will report an error from ffmpeg to $? in the pipeline.
set -o pipefail

ffmpeg -i ${input} -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+faststart -hide_banner -y pipe:1 2> progress.log | \
aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/video/output.mp4 2> ffmpeg.log
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to build /upload output.mp4"
    # Do anything else on error here...
fi

aws s3 cp progress.log s3://my-bucket/video/progress.log
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to upload progress.log"
fi

aws s3 cp ffmpeg.log s3://my-bucket/video/ffmpeg.log
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to upload ffmpeg.log"
fi
```

You could also combine the logs into one with `{...}`.  Like this:

```
{
    ffmpeg -i ${input} -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+faststart -hide_banner -y pipe:1 | \
    aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/video/output.mp4
} 2> ffmpeg.log
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot. One thing to note about the `progress.log` is FFMPEG appends data to the end of file a few times a second. After thinking about it, putting that on S3 may not even work for that.